# Cloudfront caching with optional query parameters

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, query-string

I'm trying to setup cloud front to cache our images, these images can accept a query param called `size`. The requests look something like these:

- `/images/cat?size=large`
- `/images/cat?size=medium`
- `/images/cat?size=small`
- `/images/cat`

Notice how the `size` parameter is optional and the server knows that in this case return the large version.

The problem is that setting the `Cache Key Settings` to use `size` as a key (like in the screenshot) works fine for the top three versions with the `size` parameter. But no caching happens at all if that parameter isn't there (which is the one that needs caching the most).

I'm not sure how to set this up to make everything cache properly. I have a hacky idea involving setting up one behaviour for `/images/*` that caches on `size` and another behaviour for `/images/*.png` that doesn't cache on any parameters (2 behaviours because the paths need to be unique). But this solution feels subpar.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the same situation here is what I discovered.

I attempted to do as described in the last paragraph with two overlapping behaviours, one with caching on `size` and one not. This approach seems to work fine so far. I will edit if I discover any pitfalls.